# SLI a 1080 ti with a 3080ti

Tags: graphics-cards, nvidia

Is it possible to use an Nvidia SLI bridge to tether both a 1080ti and a 3080ti? Furthermore, if it is possible, would there be any performance hiccups that may occur due to using an older and newer version of the graphics architectures?

Comment: You can't SLI dissimilar GPUs. Also. I distinctly recall newer nvidia GPUs that do SLI style stuff uses a different physical nridge

Comment: It is noteworthy that the cards can still both be utilized if they are installed in the same system. Either by plugging in several monitors to take advantage of 6+ displays, or using software that allows GPU selection for its acceleration. Such as Adobe Premiere which can use a specific GPU for rendering. Also for DX12 or Vulkan games that support multi-GPU (most games have not supported it though).

Answer (score 1):

the 3080ti has no nvlink or sli connection, it cannot run in sli at all.
it is also not possible to run two different generation gpu's in sli.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an SLI/nvidia user, so take this answer with a grain of salt

I think SLI uses an nvlink connector on RTX cards, instead of the older SLI connector. So I think this is not possible, but that doesnt have to do with the generation difference. And then, why do you want SLI? Its almost dead.